# Lose MongoDB ObjectId value when passing through Actions

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, asp.net-mvc-4, action

In my MVC `Controller`, I have this code (after adding an object, I redirect user to edit that object):

```
    [PrivilegeRequirement("DB_ADMIN")]
    public ActionResult Add()
    {
        MongoDataContext dc = new MongoDataContext();

        var model = new ModelObj();
        dc.Models.Insert(model);

        return this.RedirectToAction("Edit", new { pId = model.Id, });
    }

    [PrivilegeRequirement("DB_ADMIN")]
    public ActionResult Edit(ObjectId? pId)
    {
        MongoDataContext dc = new MongoDataContext();

        var model = dc.Models.FindOneById(pId);
        if (model == null)
        {
            Session["error"] = "No model with this ID found.";
            return this.RedirectToAction("");
        }

        return this.View(model);
    }
```

However, pId is always null, making the `FindOneById` always return null. I have debugged and made sure that the Id had value when passing from `Add` Action. Moreover, I tried adding a testing parameter:

```
    [PrivilegeRequirement("DB_ADMIN")]
    public ActionResult Add()
    {
        MongoDataContext dc = new MongoDataContext();

        var model = new ModelObj();
        dc.Models.Insert(model);

        return this.RedirectToAction("Edit", new { pId = model.Id, test = 10 });
    }

    [PrivilegeRequirement("DB_ADMIN")]
    public ActionResult Edit(ObjectId? pId, int? test)
    {
        MongoDataContext dc = new MongoDataContext();

        var model = dc.Models.FindOneById(pId);
        if (model == null)
        {
            Session["error"] = "No model with this ID found.";
            return this.RedirectToAction("");
        }

        return this.View(model);
    }
```

When I debug, I received the `test` parameter in `Edit` Action with value of 10 correctly, but pId is null. Please tell me what I did wrong, and how to solve this problem?

Comment: It's likely not (de)serializing correctly. I usually use strings to pass an `ObjectId` value when using the Web API, and then internally construct the ObjectId from the string.

Comment: @WiredPrairie Thank you, converting to string and passes them works. Please post your answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suspect that the ObjectId is not serializing/deserializing correctly. Given that it doesn't make for a great WebAPI anyway, I generally use a `string` and convert within the method to an `ObjectId` via the [`Parse`](http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/current/html/3321e7aa-fe9b-4940-be93-019ff33fed5d.htm) method (or use [`TryParse`](http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/current/html/439425f3-9480-1a19-1dd7-b257070d22b2.htm)):

```
public ActionResult Edit(string id, int? test)
{
    // might need some error handling here .... :)
    var oId = ObjectId.Parse(id);

}
```

You can use `ToString` on the `ObjectId` to convert it to a string for calling:

```
var pId = model.Id.ToString();
```